# Android : Drive app and Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api, android-contentresolver, google-drive-android-api

I would like to import files from Installed Google Drive App to my app using the **Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT**
and the mimetype of the intent set to "*/*".

I am able to do this with other installed app like Dropbox,Onedrive and box, but not with Google Drive.
Here is my code :

```
Intent action = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);          
            action.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);         
action = action.setType("*/*").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(action, "Upload file from..."),Constants.FILE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what "but not with Google Drive" means. Is Google Drive not showing up in the chooser? Is it showing up in the chooser, but then not letting you select a file? Is it letting you select a file, but you do not get called with `onActivityResult()`? BTW, try getting rid of your `addCategory()` call.

Comment: I doubt very much that Drive supports that Intent. It's possible to use the Google Drive API for Android, but that will only expose files which were created by, or previously opened (at drive.google.com) by your app.

Comment: @ CommonsWare, Yes google drive app is not showing in chooser.

Comment: @pinoyyid, Any idea? Is there any other intent can work for Drive App?I have already done for Dropbox, Ondrive and Box App only Google Drive App is blocking.

Comment: @Harry did you find the answer already ?

Comment: @Harry, did you find any solution for google drive?

Comment: @Harry, Can you please share the solution for onedrive and Dropbox, i am facing same issue

Answer (score 2):

Very late answer but you need to remove `action.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);` in order to see Google Drive option in the picker.